# Eclipse: required '@Nonnull Type' prevents JUnit test

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, compiler-errors, nullable

### My methods so far

I have a method with such a signature:

```
public static MyObject mapToOther(final MyInputType domain) {
  Objects.requireNonNull(domain, () -> "message if domain is null");
  // code …
  return new MyObject;
}
```

Also, in `package-info.java`, I have set:

```
@CheckReturnValue
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
package my.package.mappers;

import javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue;
```

I then created a JUnit test to check if a NullPointerException is being thrown if `null` is given as parameter.

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void testNpe_null() {
  MyClass.mapToOther(null);
}
```

### The problem

The test is just fine as I want to test for an NPE. But instead eclipse is complaining:

```
Null type mismatch: required '@Nonnull MyInputType' but the provided value is null
```

Well, the message is absolutely correct. But for this test it is a false positive because I am intentionally handing over `null` as a parameter value.

### What I tried so far

Can I Eclispe make not report intentional null to nonnull methods? I know I can disable it completely using this dialog:

```
Window -> Preferences ->  Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Section 'Null Analysis'
```

But there is no option to exclude methods in `src/test/java` or having a `@SuppressWarnings` annotation configured.

Now my Java problem view is flooded with errors, most of which are in test classes. Is eclipse really that stupid? I‘m using Oxygen.

### Side note

Special Kudos to the answer with maven integration. ;-)
Also, as a side note: Spotbugs is complaining that I am not checking the return value in my junit test…

Comment: In the JUnit test, does `@SuppressWarning("null")` not work?

Comment: No, the hint is: "At least one of the problems in category 'null' is not analysed due to a compiler option being ignored".

Comment: The message "At least one of the problems ..." should only indicate that the compiler 'tends to think' that the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation is unnecessary (but isn't 'sure'). Still, that would only produce a warning, not an error, right? Perhaps what you are missing is `[x] Suppress optional errors with '@SuppressWarnings'` ?

Answer (score 0):

Either the parameter must not be `null` which means that the behavior of the method is undefined for `null` and does not have to be tested, or it can be `null` and the parameter is annotated with `@Nullable`.

However, with a `null` constant it is possible (although I would not recommend this hack):

```
private static final Object NULL = null;

@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
@SuppressWarnings("null")
public void testNpe_null() {
  MyClass.mapToOther((MyInputType) NULL);
}
```

Note, this only works if the constant `NULL` is not in a `@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault` package.

Comment: Eclipse still recognizes that the parameter will be null and print the very same message. Also, if you don't annotate @Nullable to the constant, eclipse will complain again.

Comment: Make sure the package that contains the JUnit test has no `package-info.java` with `@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault`.

Comment: It's the same package as the tested class, as per convention.

Comment: Only the constant `NULL` must be in a package without `@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault` (see my edited answer).

Comment: @Ben Did you try to put the constant `NULL` in a separate package without a `package-info.java`?

Comment: That wouldn't help either, because the method is annotated with @NonNull parameters

Comment: @Ben I tested it exactly as you described it with Eclipse Oxygen.1a: it works. Please try the solution and if there are any problems, please tell where.

Comment: BTW: the Eclipse annotations allow you to cancel `@NonNullByDefault` for individual declarations - which would avoid the hassle of placing `NULL` into a specific package.